# Rubymine doesn't detect Imagemagick install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip, rubymine

I just installed Rubymine, and Imagemagick through the terminal for use with Rails Papercilp. For some reason if I run the Rails server through terminal everything works, but if I run the server through Rubymine, it says Imagemagick is missing.

Anyone have any thoughts? I've been trying to figure out this config issue for hours now.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely that imagemagick is not in your PATH in Rubymine.  The Rubymine environment is different from shell.  See http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1160;jsessionid=1858A969645F39423219A415388AF557 for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

probably, not the best way to handle it in general, but quick-n-dirty solution is

from terminal:

```
$ rvm use [environment@you_want]
```

(or just cd into ruby app folder if you use .rvmrc)

```
$ open /Applications/RubyMine.app
```

(or any other valid path to RubyMine installation)

this will load all necessary environment...

cheers